# Using vectors within a class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to use a class member vector of user defined type.

My header file is as follows:

```
class Sphere blah blah;

class Scene{  
public:
    std::vector<Sphere> Spheres; //Container of spheres.  
    LightSource Source;
};
```

When I try and then access this vector, as follows, I get an  error:

```
Scene AScene;

Sphere SampleSphere(0,-3,10,5);
(AScene.Spheres).push_back(SampleSphere);
```

What I'm trying to do is create a scene which holds a few things, including a vector of spheres.  I created a Scene (AScene), and then using push_back to add spheres to it.  This doesn't work though.  I have all the necessary preprocessor directives, so sadly it isn't that simple.

Error is:

Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall LightSource::LightSource(void)" (??0LightSource@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Scene::Scene(void)" (??0Scene@@QAE@XZ)    C:\Users\Stuart\Desktop\THE_PROJECT\THE_PROJECT\Source.obj  THE_PROJECT

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why the brackets around (AScene.Spheres)?

Comment: "This doesn't work though" ?

Comment: Edited the question to include error.  Sorry !

Comment: The error is clear enough, and nothing to do with the vector. You've declared a default constructor for `LightSource`, and haven't defined it.

Comment: Thanks.  I feel like an idiot, but I can't decipher that text down the bottom.  Thanks again!  Is it stackoverflow etiquette to delete a question as useless as this?  If so, I will!  Thanks again!

Comment: @StuartWalker yes, go ahead and delete it. It wont be of any help for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You're not linking a library.

Where is LightSoruce defined?
If it's some external library you need to link that library into your final binary.

If it's one of you own libraries, you need to link the object file into the final binary. Also you might have forgotten to declare the constructor of `LightSoruce::LightSource()`.

It's OK if you have missing symbols at an object level, but not OK in a binary or library.

If you use gcc you should have a `-llightsourcelib` or somehting like that using the right library name on the command line.

Comment: it is also possible like Mike Seymour comments suggests, it is that the function is declared in the header, but not defined in a cpp file, this way unreferenced for linking. That should be worth adding to your answer.